# How can I create a body with a hole in the middle?

Tags: c#, farseer-physics-engine

I want to create a shape that looks like the black contour in this picture:

[image]

The shape must be empty in the middle(white surface). The white surface must not be part of the shape, just the black contour should be a shape.

How can I create such a shape?

I already tried it with the BayazitDecomposer, but it's not working. The BayazitDecomposer makes a shape of the entire picture(white surface+black contour).

**UPDATE:**

It's not working. I tried it with TriangulationAlgorithm.Delauny but it doesn't create the hole. You can see the result in this debug view picture:

[image: Farseer DebugView]

My code:

```
List<Vertices> list = new List<Vertices>();
Vector2 _origin;
float _scale;

HoleSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("hole");
uint[] data = new uint[HoleSprite.Width * HoleSprite.Height];
HoleSprite.GetData(data);
Vertices textureVertices = PolygonTools.CreatePolygon(data, HoleSprite.Width, false);
Vector2 centroid = -textureVertices.GetCentroid();
textureVertices.Translate(ref centroid);
_origin = -centroid;
textureVertices = SimplifyTools.ReduceByDistance(textureVertices, 4f);
list = Triangulate.ConvexPartition(textureVertices, TriangulationAlgorithm.Delauny);
_scale = 1f;

//scale the vertices from graphics space to sim space
Vector2 vertScale = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(1)) * _scale;
foreach (Vertices vertices in list)
{
  vertices.Scale(ref vertScale);
}

Body Contour = BodyFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(world, list, 1.0f, BodyType.Dynamic);
Contour.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
```

Comment: Farseer: "The Bayazit algorithm ... It does not officially support holes, but sometimes you get lucky and it works with holes."

Comment: Farseer: "The ear clipping ... It is easy to use but does not support holes..."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to try the Delaunay decomposer:

https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/462917

https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SourceFiles/Common/Decomposition/CDTDecomposer.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// 2D constrained Delaunay triangulation algorithm.
/// Based on the paper "Sweep-line algorithm for constrained Delaunay triangulation" by V. Domiter and and B. Zalik
/// 
/// Properties:
/// - Creates triangles with a large interior angle.
/// - Supports holes
/// - Generate a lot of garbage due to incapsulation of the Poly2Tri library.
/// - Running time is O(n^2), n = number of vertices.
/// - Does not care about winding order.
/// 
/// Source: http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/
/// </summary>
internal static class CDTDecomposer
{...}
```

Comment: It's not working with TriangulationAlgorithm.Delauny.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson Can you try making the black contour thicker? Maybe even just a big rectangle with a small circle inside - to see if it works at all.

Comment: I tried it with a much thicker black contour and I made another test with a big rectangle with a small circle inside, but none of them worked. Maybe Farseer can't handle holes.